# How do I compare two files in unix based on their columns

Tags: linux, csv, unix

I am fairly new to unix commands, but i have two .csv files where i would like to compare the first column either with diff or comm. Every line is different, if i were to compare the whole line, thats why i want to compare the first column in each file and then have the difference printed out in numbers where the landcode sould not be counted more than once.  The first file has also has a header i want to skip when it compares.

sample from **file1**:

```
 iso_code,continent,location,date,total_cases 
 AND,Denver ,America,2020-07-26,897.0
 ABW,Copenhagen Denmark,,2020-03-13,2.0
 AFG,Oslo,Norway,2020-09-06,324.0
 AZE,Hamburg,Germany,2020-03-30,29.0
```

sample from **file2**:

```
AND,Denver ,America,2020-07-26,897.0
ABW,Copenhagen Denmark,,2020-03-13,5.0
ABW,Chil Ukrain,Aruba,2020-10-06,4449.0
ALB,Upsala,Sweden,2020-08-275.0,
AFG,Afghanistan,,2020-09-06,324.0
```

The expected output should be "2", as there are two occurrences of the same land code in the two files. Duplicates of the contry code sould only be counted one time. That is why expected out should be 2 and not 3

I have tried multiple solutions:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] == 0' owid-covid-data-filtered.csv owid-covid-data.csv | wc -l
```

with the awk i get output: 1

and

```
 diff owid-covid-data.csv owid-covid-data-filtered.csv |cut -d' ' -f1 owid-covid-data-filtered.csv| wc -l
```

**overall i want the occurrences that are similar in both file1 and file2 column 1**

Comment: and what output did those solutions provide, and why was that wrong?

Comment: @underscore_d my output was 51798, which is all the lines in the files. The result should be closer to about 200.

Comment: Please clarify in your question: Is the expected output 2 because there are two codes in file2 that are not present in file1?

Comment: Your `awk ... | wc -l` returns 2 as you expected.. What is wrong with that? What is the question you are asking?

Comment: @JamesBrown sorry forgot to mention, that with the awk i get "awk: can't open file file"

Comment: And why would that be? Do the files exist? Do you have the right to open them?

Comment: @JamesBrown the output is now 1. out of a 51798 line file. With the awk. Something is wrong with it

Comment: Please make clear in your question if you want to count the codes from `file2` that are **present in `file1`** or that are **not present in `file1`**. (Your `awk` condition `c[$1] == 0` will print lines that were not found in `file1`.)

Comment: @Bodo yes sorry, i want to have the amount of occurrences that are present in both file1 and file2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the condition `c[$1] == 0` in the `awk` script from the question I assumed you want to print lines from `file2` that contain a code that is **not present** in `file1`.

As it is clarified now, that you want to count the codes that are present in both files, **see below at the end of the answer** for the reverse check.

Slight modifications to your script will fix the problems:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR { if(NR!=1)c[$1]++; next} c[$1]++ == 0' file1 file2
```

Option `-F ,` specifies comma (`,`) as field separator.

The condition `if(NR!=1)c[$1]++;` skips the header line in `file1`.

The post-increment operator in `c[$1]++ == 0` will make the condition fail for the second or later occurrence of the same code in `file2`.

I omit the trailing `| wc -l` here to show the output lines.

I modified `file2` to contain two lines with the same code in column 1 that is not present in `file1`.

With `file2` shown here

```
AND,Europe,Andorra,2020-07-26,897.0
ABW,North America,Aruba,2020-03-13,2.0
ABW,North America,Aruba,2020-10-06,4079.0
ALB,Europe,Albania,2020-08-23,8275.1
ALB,Europe,Albania,2020-08-23,8275.2
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-09-06,38324.0
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-09-06,38324.0
```

and `file1` from the question I get this output:

```
AND,Europe,Andorra,2020-07-26,897.0
ALB,Europe,Albania,2020-08-23,8275.1
```

(Only the first line with `ALB` is printed`.)

You can also implemente the counting in `awk` instead of using `wc -l`.

```
awk -F , 'NR==FNR { if(NR!=1)c[$1]++; next } c[$1]++ == 0 {count++} END {print count}' file1 file2
```

---

If you want to print the lines from `file2` that contain a code that **is present** in `file1`, the script can be modified like this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR { if(NR!=1)c[$1]++; next} c[$1] { c[$1]=0; print}' file1 file2
```

This prints

```
ABW,North America,Aruba,2020-03-13,2.0
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-09-06,38324.0
```

(The first line with code `ABW`.)

---

Alternative solution as requested in a comment.

```
tail -n +2 file1|cut -f1 -d,|sort -u>code1
cut -f1 -d, file2|sort -u>code2
fgrep -vf code1 code2
rm code1 code2
```

Or combined in one command without using temporary files `code1` and `code2`:

```
fgrep -f <(tail -n +2 file1|cut -f1 -d,|sort -u) <(cut -f1 -d, file2|sort -u)
```

Add `| wc -l` to count the lines instead of printing them.

Explanation:

`tail -n +2` print everything starting from the 2nd line
`cut -f1 -d,` print the first field, delimited with `,`
`sort -u` sort lines and remove duplicates
`fgrep -f code1 code2` print all lines from `code2` that contain any of the strings from `code1`

Comment: Out of pure curiosity and to learn, is there also a way to do it with grep or comm ?

Answer (score 0):

***occurrences that are similar in both file1 and file2 column 1***:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
ABW,North America,Aruba,2020-03-13,2.0
ABW,North America,Aruba,2020-10-06,4079.0
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-09-06,38324.0
```